# How to inject extra data into entity reference checkbox form widget

Tags: forms

I've a taxonomy tree used in an entity reference field, which requires some custom rules (e.g. *if any option of subtree A is chcked, then any option of subtree B is disallowed* or *if any option of subtree C is checked, parents must be checked too*).

The field widget for this tree is set to multi-value option buttons (checkboxes). I need to create some JS behaviors that assist editors with those rules during input. I need extra info from the taxonomy term entity so my JS behaviors can act on it.

Currently the form element if rendered like this:

```
<input data-drupal-selector="edit-FIELD-MY-TAXONOMY-ID" type="checkbox" id="edit-FIELD-MY-TAXONOMY-ID" name="FIELD-MY-TAXONOMY[ID]" value="ID" class="form-checkbox form-boolean form-boolean--type-checkbox">
```

I need extra informatio like this

```
<input data-term-parent-id="XXX" data-term-field-foo-value="YYY" ...>
```

I know how to write PHP entity queries and the JS, but I don't know which hook to use to inject my those attributes. I've tried `hook_field_widget_single_element_form_alter` , `hook_field_widget_complete_form_alter` and `template_preprocess_form_element` - and not a single one of these contains information about the taxonomy term entity or the vocabulary, they all just "see" the IDs and labels as strings (and the label strings are not even the term titles, they have `-` in front if them due hierarchy).

The taxonomy is used in multiple nodes with multiple different field names, so guessing on field name is not a good idea. Which hook allows me to alter the checkbox form element AND contains a **reliable** link to the reference entity object?

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried hook_field_widget_single_element_form_alter ,
> hook_field_widget_complete_form_alter ... and not a single one of
> these contains information about the taxonomy term entity or the
> vocabulary ... contains a reliable link to the reference entity
> object?

The main object for fields is the field item list, which is provided in $context. From there you can go up to get the parent entity:

```
$entity = $context['items']->getEntity();
```

or downstream to get the referenced entities. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/309863/47547

Which can be taxonomy terms depending on whether you have placed the field in a vocabulary or your field is storing references to taxonomy terms. In either case the bundle name is the vocabulary.